# Axios Post request Is Not Working it is Changing to get request

Tags: django, axios

I Am trying To Send Post request to The Django using Axios But it Is Not Working
instead it sending get request after the submit button is pressed.
I don't know why this happening I Hvae configured Everything corretelty but it is not working
Any Has Any solution to this then please help me
My Html Code Is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Out</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.3/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-0qU9M9jfqPw6FKkPafM3gy2CBAvUWnYVOfNPDYKVuRTel1PrciTj+a9P3loJB+j0QmN2Y0JYQmkBBS8W+mbezg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
{% load static %}
</head>
<body>
    
    <div align = "center">
        <form action="" name = "out" id ="out" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Stock_out</th>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="stock_out" name="stock_out"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td><span id ="name_er"></span></td>
                    <td><span id ="stock_err"></span></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" form = "out" onclick="submit()">
        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'out.js/'%}"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Here Is My Js Script

```
function submit(){

    let nam = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let out = document.getElementById('stock_out').values


    if(nam=="" | nam==null){
        document.getElementById('nam-er').innerHTML="Name Insert please"
        return false
    
    }else{
        let form = document.getElementById('out');

        var data = new FormData(form);

        data.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
        data.append('stock_out', document.getElementById('stock_out').value);
        data.append("csrfmiddelwaretoken",'{{csrf_token}}');

        // form.reset();
        
        axios.post('add/product_out',data).then(function(resp){
            window.location.href = "add/success";
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }
    
}
```

Here Is My Django Views

> 

```
def product_out(request):
    if request.method =='POST':

        name = request.POST.get('name')
        stock = request.POST.get('stock_out')
        Stock_Out.objects.create(
            name=name,
            stock_out=stock
        )
        resp = {
        "status":'success'
        }
        return JsonResponse(resp)
```

urls.py

> 

```
from django.urls import path
from add import views


urlpatterns =[

    path('add',views.add, name='add'),
    path('success',views.success, name='success'),
    path('stock_out',views.stock_out, name = 'stock_out'),
    path('product_out',views.product_out, name = 'product_out')
    
]
```

I Want Send The to The Server from input field Which is Shown on the picture that come from http response from the browser(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrMS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the browser's default submit is triggering making it skip all your javascript part. Try preventing it with `preventDefault()`:

1. Pass the event to your js (note the `e` in the parenthesis)
   `<input type="button" value="Submit" form = "out" onclick="submit(e)">`
2. Prevent the default behaviour:

```
function submit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // ..the rest of your script here
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the submit button from being a `<input type="submit" />` to a `<button type="button">Submit</button>`

Comment: Okay Let me Try It